# Create a calendar event on Palm OS

Tags: palm-os, garnet-os

I've been googling for a while now, and can't figure out how to create an event in the calendar on a newer Palm OS device.  Any ideas on how to do this?  I'm guessing that I'll be creating a record in the calendar database, but the format of the data in that record, and which database to put it in, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Palm's later devices, they moved to an extended format for the PIM applications like Contacts and Calendar.  This was done to allow better mapping between the device's databases and those used by Microsoft Outlook, but it meant that the format changed from the traditional format in the original PIMs.

Palm has a PIM Access SDk available from [the Palm Developer Network site](https://pdnet.palm.com/) that includes code for accessing these database formats.  The devices also support the original database using a shadow version of the DB and system libraries that translate changes back and forth to the shadows.  However, the shadow DBs don't have all the data that the extended DBs have, and the conversion isn't always triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, literally ten seconds after I posted this question, I got an email from the palm developer network that led me right where I needed to go.  Frustrating.  It appears that you'll need the PIM SDK, which is available through the Palm Developer network [here](https://dts.pdn.palm.com/cgi-bin/palmdev.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=418&p_lva=1378&p_sid=zaz2d2ej&p_redirect=1).

Comment: I know I duplicated your answer some, but I wanted to give more background on this.